# Contradicting definitions for atomic mass unit?

Tags: definition, units

I have seen online that the [amu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_(unit)) is equal to approximately $1.661 \times 10^{-27}\,\text{kg}$ and is $\frac{1}{12}$ the mass of carbon-12. However, I have also seen it described as the average nucleon mass and equal to approximately $1.673 \times 10^{-27}\,\text{kg}$. Are both definitions widely used?

Comment: 1.661 is approximately 1.673, or vice versa.

Comment: @my2cts, more precisely: 1.661 is approximately 99.3% of 1.673. That's a ratio that can be ignored for _some_ purposes, but may be significant in other situations.

Comment: Does that explain how it happened?

Answer (score 2):

The first definition is correct – the atomic mass unit (or Dalton) is defined to be $1/12$ the mass of carbon-12. The [IUPAC definition](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/U06554) elaborates on this:

> Non-SI unit of mass (equal to the atomic mass constant), defined as one twelfth of the mass of a carbon-12 atom in its ground state and used to express masses of atomic particles, $u\approx1.660\;5402(10)\times10^{−27}\,\text{kg}$.

This definition was also [not affected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton_(unit)#2019_redefinition_of_the_SI_base_units) by the 2019 redefinition of SI base units.

It is in fact true that the average nucleon mass is about $1.673 \times 10^{-27}\,\text{kg}$, though this is not used as a definition for the atomic mass unit – it might be helpful to provide the sources that claim so. Another possibility might be that the second (wrong) "definition" for the atomic mass unit was actually referring to the mass of hydrogen-1 [which is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen) $1.008\,\text u\approx1.673\times10^{-27}\,\text{kg}$.

Comment: It's also true that the amu is *approximately* the average mass of a nucleon, to better than 1% accuracy.  That might be good enough in some circumstances, and I could envision some introductory textbooks glossing over this distinction for the sake of being more easily understood.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the former definition is correct. Such an exact value only became an issue when technology allowed us to care about any actual differences in the mass of nucleons. Until then, the best estimate at the time had been 1.673 and had become the standard convention by use.

But when it came time to standardize, the IUPAC needed something rigorous, not the colloquial best-estimate, and needed something they felt would be most representative - because the masses differ by proton/neutron and slightly by atom. Carbon-12 fits both. It is 12 nucleons with half protons and half neutrons (a fairly representative ratio) and was measurable.

The first one is right. The second is old. But papers from the past are sometimes sighted a lot, plus books.. anything published.